# how to resume download in wget for google takeout data

Tags: debian, ubuntu, wget, download, deb

I have 13 GB gmail data based on a discussion here

https://superuser.com/questions/1502126/13-66-gb-out-of-15-gb-used-in-gmail-delete-emails-that-consumed-space

I decided to download all emails in mbox format using google takeout.
I signed and got a link after 24 hours to download all data.
I have a slow connection so when some interruption happened I decided to switch to my mobiles 4G connection inside the virtual machine in which I was downloading my data some how I got dns resolution failures. So I switched back to my broadband connection.

Now starts the problem I was downloading part 1 of 13 Gb of google take out data from a lik that was generated via google in following format

```
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ wget -c https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
The name is too long, 1076 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is 20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffff.
--2019-12-13 23:28:19--  https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
Resolving ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com (ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com)... 100.100.100.100, 2404:6800:4002:80e::2001
Connecting to ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com (ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com)|100.100.100.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14619080679 (14G) [application/mbox]
Saving to: ‘20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffff’

20191210T045548Z%2F-118364947890465   4%[==>                                                              ] 646.74M   159KB/s    in 77m 34s 

2019-12-14 00:46:06 (142 KB/s) - Read error at byte 678159986/14619080679 (Connection reset by peer). Retrying.

--2019-12-14 00:46:07--  (try: 2)  https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
Connecting to ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com (ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com)|100.100.100.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ wget -c https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
The name is too long, 1076 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is 20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffff.
--2019-12-14 00:46:54--  https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
Resolving ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com (ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com’
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ wget -c https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
The name is too long, 1076 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is 20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffff.
--2019-12-14 00:49:17--  https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
Resolving ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com (ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com)... 172.217.166.1
Connecting to ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com (ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com)|172.217.166.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ wget -c https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
The name is too long, 1076 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is 20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffff.
--2019-12-14 00:50:21--  https://ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/dataliberation/o/20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80%2F1%2Fa32b647d-0c0e-4ea7-9bb5-8d193671ce36?qk=AD5uMEt7CLm9l6vzhiNkCBTu0CFK40PSXxP9YEVW3cj6ZmGdNDXVTffffq99IL6gNLagLO8FDoBWEsVlO8A2a5ield7YUNM4BqXkaiKPxvqUadRHw8csda7Aas9nF9JGJniOj9xWC2q9F-NaCkGtgDCAcg3zfn3iFLxHD-oiLo4ulH2xdcFsfyIGhVXFgnjmEGr6zcDYQztrGqaSHojzjnFnZiB0c4_i4q-lqqlJo3Esc5pitpu1VpxFiY05YNXCY41RRWoIqS_1BeBMrdRoU4YCVSqJGBtS9hXKr8QgWIDQDbAw0FAiT9I3GxL8UbCbRRX8IcWGErFv_ST_aewgv-m5W0lphX9BciZHFmj8AslB61eiXOGjt-7tEehJ8QwBv5vuX3rPt56x2_EIr-dwStZHLD3zZMMvZTiwjqiwR39Ptd107HeBJPoSn3QxEplPL3sNXpKVyxqjJvQI0cFGtsSFUJjEUt5hWbjg6M08LpZ012W9SYVYZ26p_tDFQfiG01uBSoFM3ql_amggIHPsjwa1Gh69J1BBJfaRNr14hlZjalif8BSoey9ifM3Ze77l8yvtd2vl9hFn1TpS9_YL6THBNoe-1Z5BW1hD4p5WYMaS9BhBCGAq9JHR8FFwnVrXuerKDU-rNh9roID4ZOcs0hWIonSXtbC2cYph9dwWhlF-6i7v3FKcl193BEiFKWTczteXH3X3st7JjjKX_A0FULtQWWQv2_0eQyf3KCPK6JLHUc0CaR_n7uqCsrX8J9F4H8JgsMnbKU4fP08ucPAlbdUK2NLp5YaRw5BqDg9woVIlAtNwOjYzCXGW5RsSnCJktXqBMlSPhknJI84HrM9leM9QVbq7hKrqN4aBixTeTS45idnQiPT3pSW1yz6WaFIP4
Resolving ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com (ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com)... 100.100.100.100, 2404:6800:4002:80e::2001
Connecting to ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com (ffff-apidata.googleusercontent.com)|100.100.100.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
```

now when I try to resume download I open in firefox the link to download all data again and new link is generated.For the new generated link I again try to download

```
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ wget -c https://takeout.google.com/takeout/download?j=ffff-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80&i=0&user=116364599410907918080&rapt=ffff
[1] 8615
[2] 8616
[3] 8617
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ 
Redirecting output to ‘wget-log’.
^C
[1]   Done                    wget -c https://takeout.google.com/takeout/download?j=ffff-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80
[2]-  Done                    i=0
```

when I do an ls to see what is the file name of previous download I see some thing like this

```
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ ls
'20191210T045548Z%2F-1183649478904650607%2F675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-
```

I am not able to understand how do I resume download in this case.
Here are a few relevant screenshots
[image: 13 gb mailbox data]
[image: 13 gb data screenshot 2]
 since I have an internet connection which disrupts so 
I have to use wget and I am not able to understand what mistake I am doing
the previously downloaded file becomes useless if for any reason download was interupted I have to authenticate myself online generate download link again but then don't know how to use previously downloaded 600 Mb or 700 Mb and in my case if I start everything a fresh connection breaks again so I am in a chicken and egg problem.

Upon issuing wget -c

```
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ wget -c https://takeout.google.com/takeout/download?j=675b18b0-9ac7-4c4d-826f-a2f96dbc8e80&i=0&user=116364599410907918080&rapt=AEjHL4MhtvhATVMv-AiHyg
[1] 8874
[2] 8875
[3] 8876
debian@osboxes:~/Downloads$ 
Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.1’.
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to quote your arguments correctly. `&` has a special meaning in shell commands (run command in the background, hence you got `[1] [2] [3]` unintentional background tasks), so for URLs that contain the `&` character, it must be quoted or it will be misunderstood.

```
$ wget http://some?special&url&parameters   # wrong
$ wget 'http://some?special&url&parameters' # correct
```

As for the incorrect filename, `wget` resumes properly even if URL filename and local filenames do not match, example:

```
$ wget -O customname -c http://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
--2019-12-13 21:01:41--  http://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
Resolving speed.hetzner.de (speed.hetzner.de)... 88.198.248.254, 2a01:4f8:0:59ed::2
Connecting to speed.hetzner.de (speed.hetzner.de)|88.198.248.254|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 104857600 (100M), 54492347 (52M) remaining [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘customname’

customname           67%[+++++++++===>       ]  67.20M  1.74MB/s    eta 20s
```

So this file is called `100MB.bin` on the webserver but saved and resumed under `customname` and it works.

However, resuming in general is a concept that has to be supported by the web server. If the webserver refuses to send partial content, it's possible you have no choice but to re-download everything from scratch.

Also I'm not entirely sure how Google download servers work. If it generates a new link every time, there's a chance it may not actually be the same file. Some places offer downloads as zipped archive that is generated on the fly so it's different every time it's generated, and trying to resume would result in a corrupted download instead.

If you have a rented vServer somewhere you could also download there first, then move it over to your unstable home connection.

Comment: yes that quotes thing you pointed out was a very silly mistake from my end and more over there seems to be a download limit once I click 2-3 times to download some data I reach download limit as you can see in screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WtQDkyGaD3hTxbPrMOwLaiX4j148YYOa/view?usp=sharing now I have requested for another email archive and it will take 2-3 days to generate from google takeout.